# Dynamically add to whiteListedDomians angular-jwt

Tags: angularjs, jwt

Trying to add urls to whiteListedDomains dynamically by using $location provider, but not working

```
jwtOptionsProvider.config({
    whiteListedDomains: [$location.host()],
    tokenGetter: ['localStorageService', function(localStorageService){
        return localStorageService.get('auth');
    }]
});
```

Comment: Do you mean this line: `whiteListedDomains: [$location.host()],`? If so, try to do a `console.log($location.host())` somewhere else to see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to achieve this, set a constant and inject it into config, the location is now dynamically injected based off the hostname, using hostname removes any protocol or ports. this is a requirement angular-jwt

```
.constant('location', {'hostname': window.location.hostname})

.config(function(location, jwtOptionsProvider) {
    jwtOptionsProvider.config({
        whiteListedDomains: [location.hostname],
        tokenGetter: ['localStorageService', function(localStorageService){
            return localStorageService.get('auth');
        }]
    });
})
```